# Should we synonym [email-integration] to [email]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[email-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email-integration)

> Questions related to integrating e-mail functionality in an existing application

[email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email)

> Use this tag for questions involving code to send or receive email messages. Posting to ask why the emails you send are marked as spam is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions about configuration of mail servers belong on Server Fault.

These two tags seem to be the same thing. If your application is sending email (or even acting as an email client), it really falls under the [email] tag. Is there some reason not to do this? Speak now or forever hold your peace

Comment: eh, well, it is a hard one - from my experience email "integration" involves subscriber management while working with third-party APIs of services like Mailchimp or SendGrid, which seems to fall out of scope defined by tag usage guidance (there is a more thorough one in the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/email/info)). There is also ~750 questions to [work through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email-integration+-email) that omit [tag:email].

Comment: @OlegValter While that's true, there still seems to be a lot of overlap between the two, even if both tags aren't used

Comment: Frankly, I mostly think it is the [tag:email] scope that is unnecessarily narrow, not that [tag:email-integration] is sufficiently different. A tweak to tag wiki and excerpt can mitigate that - not sure why managing campaigns would not be considered "about email". That said, there 
 are a [bunch of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bemail-integration%5D+-%5Bemail%5D+-send+-receive+is%3Aq) (~260) that do not have [tag:email] and do not contain either "send" or "receive" keywords - maybe they need to be looked into (I suspect they are in part off-topic and belong on Server Fault).

Comment: Where's an answer so we can vote on it?

Comment: @OlegValter are you sure it is narrow? It covers every library ever created to send and receiving emails. Also, managing campaings are absolutely off topic, unless they involve an API, in which case it would use the specific api tag, like mailchipm-api.

Comment: @Braiam - we have a different view on the value of abstract tags, I don't think it is going to be productive :( That said, as for the scope of the [tag:email] - *outside of the merits of it as a tag* - I do think it is narrowed too much to "send and receive" as emailing is much more than that. Re: campaigns - I was talking about the API, but that's certainly not clear from the comment, sorry. I would expect [tag:email] *and* [tag:mailchimp] to be present, as a lot of API features of mailing services are unrelated to email. Being able to distinguish between them is important, I think.

Comment: @Joshua Voting on the question if you merely support or oppose is all we need. If you type one up we can vote on it, but a lot of negative votes would indicate there's no support for it.

Comment: @OlegValter I ask you because campaigns are implicitly included in the "send" part of the definition. It's by default already all encompassing of everything email related with its current wording. That's precisely why I don't see the need of it at all. A mailchimp question isn't more likely to be answered with the extra tag. If this site was about sys admin or network admin, I would have seen people expert on this. Programmers aren't expert in emails.

Comment: @Braiam - probably better to include that explicitly then if the [tag:email-integration] is to be removed. I am a proponent of tag composition over "there must be an expert on" approach: [tag:email][tag:html] offers more search flexibility than [tag:html-email] (also existent on SO and which I would gladly synonymize to [tag:email]). With 60K watchers, [tag:email] exposes the question to much more users than [tag:mailchimp]. With all that, it still satisfies the criteria of marking what the question is about.

Answer (score -10):

Frankly, I see no purpose of any of those. For emails, the programmer usually leaves that responsibility to an MTA or a library. In fact, a cursory glance to both tags show that other than the language, the most popular tags used with those questions are said libraries (or frameworks, looking at you wordpress). That covers "questions involving code to send or receive email messages" and "integrating e-mail functionality".

We don't need tags that covers every library ever created to handle emails, both should just be gone. They are ambiguous, a large portion is outside of the scope of this site (MTA administration), it's [pushing out more relevant tags](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66257633/revisions) causing harm, it's overly board describing the technologies that can be used in several context, and doesn't say something more specific about the skills required to answer the question.

Instead of synonym, just remove them.

Comment: I disagree that both tags should be removed. Popular questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649014/send-email-using-java) would then only be tagged with *java*, which sounds counterproductive.

Comment: @Lino why would it be counter productive to have a single tag if that's all it needs? If you want two tags, why not create a tag for javax.mail (I'm actually surprised that nobody did this)? It has it [own page](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/package-summary.html) describing the api, and for what I can tell, it's complex enough to have it's own tag, no?